# How to execute code after action finished in vue js?

Tags: vue.js, action, toastr

How to execute code after action finished in vue js? this is my login action

```
  login: async ({commit},loginDTO)=>{
         return  commit('login',loginDTO);
  }
```

My login mutations is this:

```
login:(state, loginDTO)=>{

 axios.post(loginEndpoint.login, loginDTO)
  .then(resp => {
    if(resp.data.statusCode == 1) {
      state.user.userId = resp.data.userId;
      state.user.response = resp.data.responseText;
      localStorage.setItem("token", "token")
      state.isLogin = true;
      router.push({name: 'Systems'});

    }
    else{
      alert(66);
      state.user.response = resp.data.responseText;
      }
  })
  .catch(err => {

  })
}
```

And I call it from component like this:

```
    methods:{
      ...mapActions(['login']),
      async login1(){

        const loginDTO = {
          Username : this.user.Username,
          Password: this.user.Password
        };
        await this.$store.dispatch('login',loginDTO);

        this.$toastr.s("Message", "");

      }
    }
```

Now I need toast message but after action is completed.
Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of async-await, and await for async action to complete and sync mutation to commit before you show the toast:

```
// action
login: async ({commit},loginDTO)=>{
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.post(loginEndpoint.login, loginDTO)
    commit('login', data.userId, data.responseText, true);
  } catch(error) {
    commit('login', null, error.message, false);
  }
}

// mutation
login: (state, userId, response, isLogin) {
  state.user.userId = userId;
  state.user.response = response;
  state.isLogin = isLogin
}

methods:{
...mapActions(['login']),
    async login1(){
    const loginDTO = {
      Username : this.user.Username,
      Password: this.user.Password
    };
    await this.$store.dispatch('login',loginDTO);
    this.$toastr.s("Message", "");
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried, it did not help, toast message execute before action copmlete

Comment: This should have worked. Can you update your question with actual code you are using while dispatching and creating the event, mutation

Comment: you are using actions and mutations incorrectly. Your application logic and mutations are all happening in one mutation, whereas it should happen in an action in a very abstract way. a mutation should just be a synchronous commit

Comment: I updated my answer with pseudocode of how your action and mutation should look like. It should work after some modifications at your end with configuration

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is call the toast function after the action complete as usual, callback function after ajax returns 200, for example, I used

`https://github.com/ankurk91/vue-toast-notification`

then run it like so on the callback

`this.$toast.open('You did it!');`

(make sure the toast has been registered on your vue instance)

Comment: I want make action async and call it using await